# Hiding navigation after clicking somewhere esle not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, onclick

I have a burger nav. After clicking the burger sidebar nav shows up and hides after clicking once more. I want to make it so I don't have to click the burger button, but I can click somewhere else (main container, etc.) and hide the sidebar.
This is the burger button code:

```
function navBurger() {
    var element = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    var burger = document.querySelector(".burger-btn");
    element.classList.toggle("extended");
    burger.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

This part works just fine, but when I add this:

```
window.onclick = function() {
    var element = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    var burger = document.querySelector(".burger-btn");
    
    if (element.classList.contains("extended")) {
        window.onclick = function() {
            element.classList.remove("extended");
            burger.classList.remove("open");
        }
    } 
}
```

Navigation will hide after the first click, but I am not able to show and then hide it after that first click. It's like the script thinks that navigation still has that class (but it was removed) and won't let the navbar be opened.
Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, after clicking the first time to open the nav, the window onclick would then remove the classes added by clicking on the menu button as the event bubbled up.  To fix this, add `event.stopPropagation()` to your menu click handler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

I also removed the re-bind of the onclick handler, as it was causing the first click to not close the menu properly.

```js
function navBurger(e) {
    console.log('button clicked')
    var element = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    var burger = document.querySelector(".burger-btn");
    element.classList.toggle("extended");
    burger.classList.toggle("open");
    // Prevents the window onclick from firing after this function runs
    // try commenting this out
    e.stopPropagation();
}

window.onclick = function() {
    console.log('onclick triggered');
    var element = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    var burger = document.querySelector(".burger-btn");
    
    if (element.classList.contains("extended")) {
        element.classList.remove("extended");
        burger.classList.remove("open");
    } 
}

document.querySelector(".burger-btn").addEventListener("click", navBurger);
```

```css
.navbar.extended {
  background: green;
}

.burger-btn.open::after {
  content: "Open";
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"><button class="burger-btn" type="button">Nav</button></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that the global click handler replaces itself with a nested, *unconditional* function to turn off the burger menu. A second click will open the menu but bubble up to the window handler and turn it off again.

The global handler needs to determine if the click is inside or outside the extended menu before turning it off. Applying the `closest` method to the click event target can help with this.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var element = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    var burger = document.querySelector(".burger-btn");
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if( burger.classList.contains("open") 
          && !event.target.closest(".extended") ) {
            // the click is outside an open extended element
            element.classList.remove("extended");
            burger.classList.remove("open");
        }    
    };
};
```

The above should close the burger menu if the user clicks outside the element with class `"extended"`. JQuery documentation covers the jQuery `closest` method and `event.target` if you wish to write the code in jQuery.

Note setting `window.onclick` is set in `window.onload` to avoid confusion, and that using `oneventname` properties of elements is better replaced  by using `addEventListener` calls in JavaScript.